# Algorithm for finding the longest prefix

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.1, pattern-matching, query-performance

I have two tables.

First one is a table with prefixes

```
code name price
343  ek1   10
3435 nt     4
3432 ek2    2
```

Second is call records with phone numbers

```
number        time
834353212     10
834321242     20
834312345     30
```

I need write a script which find longest prefix from prefixes for each record, and write all this data to third table, like this:

```
 number        code   ....
 834353212     3435
 834321242     3432
 834312345     343
```

For number 834353212 we must trim '8', and then find the longest code from prefix table, its 3435.
We must always drop first '8' and prefix must be in the beginning.

I solved this task long time ago, with very bad way.
Its was terrible perl script which do a lot of queries for each record.
This script:

1. Take a number from calls table, do substring from length(number) to
   1 => $prefix in the loop
2. Do the query  : select count(*) from prefixes where code like '$prefix'
3. If count>0 then take first prefixes and write into table

First problem is query counts - it's `call_records * length(number)`.
Second problem is `LIKE` expressions. I am afraid those are slow.

I tried to solve the second problem by:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX prefix_idx ON prefix USING gist (code gist_trgm_ops);
```

That speeds up each query, but did not solve problem in general.

I have **20k** prefixes and **170k** numbers now, and my old solution is bad. Looks like I need some new solution without loops.

Only one query for each call record or something like this.

Comment: I am not really sure if `code` in the first table is the same as prefix later.  Could you please clarify it?  And some fixing of the example data and desired output (so that it is easier to follow your problem) will be also welcome.

Comment: Yep. You right. I was forget write about '8'. Thank you.

Comment: the prefix has to be at the beginning, right?

Comment: Yes. From second place. 8$prefix$numbers

Comment: What's the cardinality of your tables? 100k numbers? How many prefixes?

Comment: 20k prefixes, about 170k numbers.

Comment: I think I have something *much* faster, yet. What are the *shortest* and the *longest* prefix in your setup?

Comment: The shortest is 1 , and the longest is 10. But more then 50% of prefixes length in 5-8

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming data type `text` for the relevant columns.

```
CREATE TABLE prefix (code text, name text, price int);
CREATE TABLE num (number text, time int);
```

#### "Simple" Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (n.number)
       n.number, p.code
FROM   num n
JOIN   prefix p ON right(n.number, -1) LIKE (p.code || '%')
ORDER  BY n.number, p.code DESC;
```

#### Key elements:

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension of the SQL standard `DISTINCT`. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860).

`ORDER BY p.code DESC` picks the longest match, because `'1234'` sorts after `'123'` (in ascending order).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=aec7293b12be1f14389612e1eac59a9f)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04440/1)</sub>

Without index, this query runs for a *very* long time (didn't wait to see it finish). We need index support. Trigram indexes (supplied by the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)) are a good candidate. You have to choose between GIN and GiST index. The first character of the numbers is just noise and can be excluded from the index, making it a functional index.
In my tests, a **functional trigram GIN index** won the race over a trigram GiST index (as expected):

```
CREATE INDEX num_trgm_gin_idx ON num USING gin (right(number, -1) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Advanced *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d8328dfbe40894419bba47669a11dbe9)*.

All test results are from a local Postgres 9.1 test installation with a reduced setup: 17k numbers and 2k codes:

- Total runtime: 1719.552 ms (trigram GiST)
- Total runtime: **912.329 ms** (trigram GIN)

### Much faster yet

#### Failed attempt with `text_pattern_ops`

Ignoring the distracting first noise character, it comes down to a basic **left anchored** pattern match. Therefore I tried a functional B-tree index with the [operator class `text_pattern_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) (assuming column type `text`).

```
CREATE INDEX num_text_pattern_idx ON num(right(number, -1) text_pattern_ops);
```

This works excellently for **direct queries** with a single search term and makes the trigram index look bad in comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM num WHERE right(number, -1) LIKE '2345%'
```

- Total runtime: 3.816 ms (trgm_gin_idx)
- Total runtime: **0.147 ms** (text_pattern_idx)

**However**, the query planner will not consider this index for joining two tables (before `LATERAL` joins existed).

#### Partial / functional B-tree indexes

The alternative it to use equality checks on partial strings with partial indexes. This *can* be used in a `JOIN`.

Since we typically only have a limited number of `different lengths` for prefixes, we can build a solution similar to the one presented here with partial indexes:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22500/3684)

Say, we have prefixes ranging from **1** to **5** characters. Create a number of partial functional indexes, one for every distinct prefix length:

```
CREATE INDEX prefix_code_idx5 ON prefix(code) WHERE length(code) = 5;
CREATE INDEX prefix_code_idx4 ON prefix(code) WHERE length(code) = 4;
CREATE INDEX prefix_code_idx3 ON prefix(code) WHERE length(code) = 3;
CREATE INDEX prefix_code_idx2 ON prefix(code) WHERE length(code) = 2;
CREATE INDEX prefix_code_idx1 ON prefix(code) WHERE length(code) = 1;
```

Since these are *partial* indexes, all of them together are barely larger than a single complete index.

Add matching indexes for numbers (taking the leading noise character into account):

```
CREATE INDEX num_number_idx5 ON num(substring(number, 2, 5)) WHERE length(number) >= 6;
CREATE INDEX num_number_idx4 ON num(substring(number, 2, 4)) WHERE length(number) >= 5;
CREATE INDEX num_number_idx3 ON num(substring(number, 2, 3)) WHERE length(number) >= 4;
CREATE INDEX num_number_idx2 ON num(substring(number, 2, 2)) WHERE length(number) >= 3;
CREATE INDEX num_number_idx1 ON num(substring(number, 2, 1)) WHERE length(number) >= 2;
```

While these indexes only hold a substring each and are partial, each covers most or all of the table. So they are much larger together than a single total index - except for long numbers. And they impose more work for write operations. That's the **cost** for amazing speed.

If that cost is too high for you (write performance is important / too many write operations / disk space an issue), you can skip these indexes. The rest is still faster, if not quite as fast as it could be ...

If numbers are never shorter then `n` characters, drop redundant `WHERE` clauses from some or all, and also drop the corresponding `WHERE` clause from all following queries.

#### Recursive CTE

With all the setup so far I was hoping for very elegant solution with a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT n.number, p.code, 4 AS len
   FROM   num n
   LEFT    JOIN prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 5) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 6  -- incl. noise character
            AND length(p.code) = 5

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.number, p.code, len - 1
   FROM    cte c
   LEFT   JOIN prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, c.len) = p.code
            AND length(c.number) >= c.len+1  -- incl. noise character
            AND length(p.code) = c.len
   WHERE    c.len > 0
   AND    c.code IS NULL
   )
SELECT number, code
FROM   cte
WHERE  code IS NOT NULL;
```

- Total runtime: **1045.115 ms**

While this query isn't bad - about as good as the simple version with a trigram GIN index - it doesn't deliver what I was aiming for. The recursive term is planned once only, so it can't use the best indexes. Only the non-recursive term can.

#### `UNION ALL`

Since we are dealing with a small number of recursions we can just spell them out iteratively. This allows optimized plans for each of them. (We lose the recursive exclusion of already successful numbers, though. So there is *still* some room for improvement, especially for a wider range of prefix lengths)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number)
       number, code
FROM  (
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 5) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 6  -- incl. noise character
            AND length(p.code) = 5
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 4) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 5
            AND length(p.code) = 4
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 3) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 4
            AND length(p.code) = 3
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 2) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 3
            AND length(p.code) = 2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 1) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 2
            AND length(p.code) = 1
   ) x
ORDER BY number, code DESC;
```

- Total runtime: **57.578 ms (!!)**

A breakthrough, finally!

#### SQL function

Wrapping this into an SQL function removes the query planning overhead for repeated use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_longest_prefix()
  RETURNS TABLE (number text, code text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number)
       number, code
FROM  (
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 5) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 6  -- incl. noise character
            AND length(p.code) = 5
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 4) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 5
            AND length(p.code) = 4
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 3) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 4
            AND length(p.code) = 3
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 2) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 3
            AND length(p.code) = 2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(number, 2, 1) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= 2
            AND length(p.code) = 1
   ) x
ORDER BY number, code DESC
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_longest_prefix_sql();
```

- Total runtime: **17.138 ms (!!!)**

#### PL/pgSQL function with dynamic SQL

This PL/pgSQL function is much like the recursive CTE above, but the dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` forces the query to be re-planned for every iteration. Now it makes use of all the tailored indexes.

Additionally, this works for **any range** of prefix lengths. The function takes two parameters for the range, but I prepared it with `DEFAULT` values, so it works without explicit parameters, too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_longest_prefix2(_min int = 1, _max int = 5)
  RETURNS TABLE (number text, code text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
FOR i IN REVERSE _max .. _min LOOP  -- longer matches first
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   SELECT n.number, p.code
   FROM   num n
   JOIN   prefix p
            ON  substring(n.number, 2, $1) = p.code
            AND length(n.number) >= $1+1  -- incl. noise character
            AND length(p.code) = $1'
   USING i;
END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

The final step cannot be wrapped into the one function easily.
*Either* just call it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number)
       number, code
FROM   f_longest_prefix_prefix2() x
ORDER  BY number, code DESC;
```

- Total runtime: **27.413 ms**

*Or use another SQL function as wrapper:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_longest_prefix3(_min int = 1, _max int = 5)
  RETURNS TABLE (number text, code text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number)
       number, code
FROM   f_longest_prefix_prefix2($1, $2) x
ORDER  BY number, code DESC
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_longest_prefix3();
```

- Total runtime: **37.622 ms**

A bit slower due to required planning overhead. But more versatile than SQL and shorter for longer prefixes.

Comment: I am still checking, but looks excellent!  Your  idea "reverse" like operator - brilliant. Why I was so stupid ;(

Comment: I just finish checks. All right. Its much better than I expect in the best way. Thank you! Thats awesome!

Comment: whoah! that's quite the edit. i wish i could upvote again.

Comment: I learn from your amazing answer more than for last two years. 17-30 ms against a several hours in my loop solution? Thats a magic.

Comment: @KorjavinIvan: Well, as documentented, I tested with a reduced setup of 2k prefixes / 17k numbers. But this should scale pretty well and my test machine was a tiny server. So you should stay well under a second with your real life case.

Comment: Nice answer... Do you know the [dimitri's prefix extension](https://github.com/dimitri/prefix)? Could you include that on your test cases comparision?

Answer (score 4):

A string S is a prefix of a string T iff T is between S and SZ where Z is lexicographically larger than any other string (eg 99999999 with enough 9's to exceed the longest possible phone number in the dataset, or sometimes 0xFF will work).

The longest common prefix for any given T is also lexicographically maximal, so a simple group by and max will find it.

```
select n.number, max(p.code) 
from prefixes p
join numbers n 
on substring(n.number, 2, 255) between p.code and p.code || '99999999'
group by n.number
```

If this is slow, it's likely due to the computed expressions, so you can also try materializing p.code ||'999999' into a column in the codes table with its own index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although Erwin's masterful-as-always answer has incredible performance, it seems to be dependent on the number of prefix characters that need to be matched, which could be tricky to maintain; in telco, e164 prefixes are effectively arbitrary, and can be remarkably long, particularly if you are going to local geographic prefixes in a country with an already long country code.

There is a less performant but far less complex solution, similar to what KWillets suggests, which still uses indexes, but not as efficiently:

```
-- Create a table of prefixes and populate it with test data.
create table prefix (code text not null);
insert into prefix select generate_series::text from generate_series(1, 20000);

-- Index on prefix table is obviously very important.
create index prefix_idx on prefix (code);

-- Create 170K random phone numbers.
create table number (e164 text);
insert into number select round(random() * 10000000000) from generate_series(1, 170000);

create or replace function find_prefix(_e164 text) returns text stable language sql as $$
  select max(code) from prefix where code <= _e164
$$;

-- Perform the query
explain analyse select e164, find_prefix(e164) from number;
```

this takes about 30 seconds to run for 170K numbers, on my laptop (about 5K CDRs/second).

Beware that this code produces the nearest prefix, which might not actually match the number. In production you would need to include something like `starts_with` to ensure that the returned prefix is an actual match.