# Postgresql subquery speed much slower than individual queries

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, performance, postgresql-performance

In Postgres 9.1. I am attempting to do a single query to get the timezone of a given postal code. I have data loaded in my database, and I am using PostGIS to store the coordinates of each postal code.  Here are the two queries that I need to do in order to get the data I need:

```
SELECT coord FROM public.postal_code WHERE postal_code = 'T1K0T4' LIMIT 1
```

query time: 6ms

This gives me the coordinate of the center of the postal_code area.  Then I use this coordinate to find which timezone it intersects:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.timezones as tz
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-112 49)',4326),geom)
```

query time: 36ms

Now when I combine the 2 queries, the query time jumps to 7-8 seconds.  This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.timezones as tz
WHERE ST_Intersects((SELECT coord FROM taduler.postal_code
                     WHERE postal_code = 'T1K0T4' LIMIT 1),geom)
```

I have a spatial index on the `coord` column in the postal_code table, and also on the `geom` column in the timezone table, but it seems like it isn't being used for the subquery.

Does anyone know of a better way to optimize this query?  I have tried several variations of this query, like joining the tables and such, but they have all resulted in the same query speed.

Output from EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Seq Scan on timezones tz  (cost=8.37..167.47 rows=136 width=335547) (actual time=4606.136..7274.428 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: st_intersects($0, (geom)::geography)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..8.37 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Index Scan using postal_code_idx on postal_code  (cost=0.00..8.37 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((postal_code)::text = 'T1K0T4'::text)
Total runtime: 7274.448 ms
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.timezones as tz
JOIN taduler.postal_code as pc on ST_Intersects(pc.coord, tz.geom)
WHERE pc.postal_code = 'T1K0T4'
```

Output:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..174.61 rows=1 width=335714) (actual time=4870.908..7572.723 rows=1 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((pc.coord && (tz.geom)::geography) AND (_st_distance(pc.coord, (tz.geom)::geography, 0::double precision, false) < 1e-05::double precision))
  ->  Index Scan using postal_code_idx on postal_code pc  (cost=0.00..8.37 rows=1 width=167) (actual time=0.012..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((postal_code)::text = 'T1K0T4'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on timezones tz  (cost=0.00..56.08 rows=408 width=335547) (actual time=0.002..2.795 rows=408 loops=1)
Total runtime: 7572.787 ms
```

Comment: please post the query plan (EXPLAIN ANALYZE)

Comment: What is the coord for that postal_code? What type and coordinate system? Because it doesn't think it can use the index. So compare the two.

Comment: "POINT(-112.823003 49.697541)" is the coord, using EPSG 4326

Comment: @Richard Huxton, I also realized the postal_code is `geography` and the timezone is using `geometry`.  That may be the issue, but I'm no expert with PostGIS.

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks to your questions, I was able to figure out that the problem was the data types of the two columns.  They both need to be the same data type, so once I changed the geometry column to geography, the query runs as expected.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: The question should have table definitions - what you get with `\d tbl` from psql.

Answer (score 4):

You are running in a weakness of the query planner: That index cannot be used in a plain join. Had a similar problem here:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-prefix/43444#43444) (Chapter "Failed attempt with text_pattern_ops")

In **Postgres 9.3** or later use a [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT coord
    FROM   taduler.postal_code
    WHERE  postal_code = 'T1K0T4'
    LIMIT  1
    ) pc
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM   public.timezones tz
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(pc.coord, tz.geom)
   ) tz ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

In **Postgres 9.1**, it might help to encapsulate the first query in a CTE, but I am not sure:

```
WITH pc AS (
    SELECT coord
    FROM   taduler.postal_code
    WHERE  postal_code = 'T1K0T4'
    LIMIT  1
    )
SELECT *
FROM   pc
JOIN   public.timezones tz ON ST_Intersects(pc.coord, tz.geom);
```

A **PL/pgSQL function** encapsulating two separate queries certainly does the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_tz(_pc text)
  RETURNS SETOF public.timezones
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _coord geom;
BEGIN
   SELECT coord
   INTO  _coord
   FROM   taduler.postal_code
   WHERE  postal_code = _pc
   LIMIT  1;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   public.timezones tz
   WHERE  ST_Intersects(_coord, tz.geom);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_get_tz('T1K0T4');
```