# SQL - find records that are prefixes of my string

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column named `prefix` storing 'aaaa'. My application has a long string, eg. 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'. I want to select all rows in which a particular column is a prefix of 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'. The length of the prefix is variable.

How can I do it in Postgres?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE '%' || prefix || '%' ILIKE 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'
```

but it does not match.

Comment: If you need to optimize performance for big tables, consider this related answer: [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-prefix/43444#43444)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your way of using `[I]LIKE` is [wrong](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

> ```
> string LIKE pattern
> ```

So, string first, pattern second.

Furthermore, as you are after prefixes only, the starting wildcard is not needed.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'aaaabbbbccccdddd' ILIKE prefix || '%';
```

A small proof of this:

```
WITH my_table (prefix) AS (
VALUES ('abcde'),
       ('abcd'),
       ('abcE'),
       ('bcde')
)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'abcdefghijkl' ILIKE prefix || '%';

 prefix 
────────
 abcde
 abcd
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to create all the prefixes of the selected word and test them with equality `=`, (or `ILIKE`<sup>*</sup>), against the strings in the table:

```
select t.prefix 
from 
  (select 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'::text as word) as w,
  generate_series(0, length(w.word)) as g,
  lateral 
  (select t.prefix 
   from my_table as t
   where t.prefix = left(w.word,g)
   -- where t.prefix ilike left(w.word,g)
  ) as t ;
```

This might be more efficient in big tables, doing only a few (as many as the length of word, +1) equality checks using index seeks and not performing a full index or table scan.

<sup>*</sup>: If you need case insensitive check, then `ILIKE` should be used as the commented code above. The improvement in this case from the `'abcdefghijkl' ILIKE prefix || '%'` answer is that the `prefix` column is used on the left of `ILIKE` and not on the right side. So, the query will be performing a few `column ILIKE 'aaabbbccdd'` checks and not (an arbitrary number of) `'aaabbbccdd' ILIKE column||'%'` checks.

Both ways we have a number of different `ILIKE` conditions but in one case that number is the length of the searching word and in the other the number of rows in the table.