# Reverse pattern matching: find the longest prefix

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, pattern-matching

I have a database with the phone rates. Rather simple one.

```
Code     Price
----     -----
1        0.005
18       0.002
1888     0.000
```

Now I have a phone number arriving to the database: 18127551221. I want to do a query and get the price of the call.

I want to be able to find longest possible match in the "Code" column. Length of the Code can be up to 6 symbols so I want something versatile.

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres and the table definition showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple query provided by Werter. It gets the job done. But performance deteriorates with a rising number of rows in table `phone_rate` because the query cannot use indexes very efficiently.

If you have **more than a trivial number** of "phone rates", since ...

> Length of the Code can be up to 6 symbols

.. there is a way to optimize performance.

Given this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE phone_rate(
   code text PRIMARY KEY
 , price numeric NOT NULL
);
```

Create 6 partial indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx6 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 6;
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx5 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 5;
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx4 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 4;
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx3 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 3;
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx2 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 2;
CREATE INDEX phone_rate_code_idx1 ON phone_rate(code) WHERE length(code) = 1;
```

Together they are just as big as a single full index.

Now we can make perfect use of **very fast index-only scans**.
I wrapped the query in an SQL function for convenience:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_matching_phone_rate(_number text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 6
   AND    left(_number, 6) = p.code

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 5
   AND    left(_number, 5) = p.code

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 4
   AND    left(_number, 4) = p.code

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 3
   AND    left(_number, 3) = p.code

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 2
   AND    left(_number, 2) = p.code

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT p.code FROM phone_rate p
   WHERE  length(p.code) = 1
   AND    left(_number, 1) = p.code
   LIMIT 1
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_matching_phone_rate('18127551221');
```

Assuming given numbers are always longer than the shortest code. Else add to each `SELECT`:

```
AND    length(number) >= 6  -- etc.
```

Since all 6 subqueries have identical structure you could easily loop in a plpgsql function. Shorter code, but it won't be faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_matching_phone_rate2(_number text, OUT code text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
    i int := 6;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT INTO code  p.code
      FROM   phone_rate p
      WHERE  length(p.code) = i
      AND    left(_number, i) = p.code;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
      i := i - 1;
      EXIT WHEN i < 1;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Same call.

Closely related, with explanation and links:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-prefix/43444#43444)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT *  
FROM prices  
WHERE '18127551221' LIKE "Code" || '%'  
ORDER BY "Code" DESC 
LIMIT 1
```